# moment DateTime format(extra -) incorrect on FireFox version 64

Tags: asp.net-mvc, momentjs

So here is a interesting issue..
Some clients of mine reported an issue posting data, no changes have been made, but  all 10 clients that have reported the issue are using the latest version of firefox(version 64).

```
var startDate = moment($("#DateString").val(), "D-MMM-YYYY").format("D-MMM-YYYY");
alert(startDate); //Firefox returns 17-Dec-2018 //Chrome 17-Dec-2018
alert($("#DateString").val()); //Firefox returns 17-Dec--2018 //Chrome 17-Dec-2018
```

Also when you inspect

```
<input class="form-control date datetime" type="text" value="17-Dec-2018" id="DateString" name="DateString" data-min-view="2" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy" title="example: 12-Nov-2015" maxlength="11">
```

but the textbox actually shows 17-Dec--2018 (firefox only)

So i'm getting an extra -, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

So it was the bootstrap datepicker I was using, for whatever mozilla changed in version 64 broke the version I was using, updated the latest version resolved it.
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker